# How to save captured image in media library?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I want Save the Captured image in Media LIbrary. Any one can help me. :)

```
CameraCaptureTask myCamera = new CameraCaptureTask();
myCamera.Show();
```

This is the code i used to open the camera and Capture

Comment: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/how-to-save-a-picture-captured-with-the-new-cameras-api-in-the-camera-roll-in-windows-phone-8/
took 5 seconds with google search

there even is a msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your `CameraCaptureTask` in your Page before the constructor:

```
CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask;
```

In the Page constructure, initialize the CameraCaptureTask and subscribe to the `Completed` event handler:

```
cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCaptureTask_Completed);
```

Call the Show method when you want to launch the task (example: in the Page constructor or on a button click event):

```
cameraCaptureTask.Show();
```

Add the code for the completed event handler to your page. This code runs after the user completes the task. The result is a PhotoResult object that exposes a stream containing the image data:

```
void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        MediaLibrary medialibrary = new MediaLibrary(); // Don't forget to the "using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;" namespace
        medialibrary.SavePicture("ImageName", e.ChosenPhoto);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Olivier, Thanks for your valubale help. Could you please  make this code more clear where i can easily understand. I want to save the image in Media Library instead of Image Control

Comment: @Dinoo, I edited my answer to show you how to save to the MediaLibrary.

Comment: Dear Olivier, Great support from you, its amazing now working fine

Comment: Dear Olivier, thanks its working, can i save this image in an Object??? so that i can send it directly to server ??? if its possible can u rough it here

Comment: @Dinoo that's another question that you should post as such on stackoverflow. And don't forget to mark this question as answered if the solution works.

Comment: @Dear Olivier, unfortunately stack overflow blocked me from asking Question, so i asked here itself.

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490347/upload-image-file-in-windows-phone-7-application-to-php and here http://chriskoenig.net/2011/08/19/upload-files-from-windows-phone/

Answer (score 0):

use the SavePictureToCameraRoll method of the MediaLibrary object

```
public async void Capture()
{
   await seq.StartCaptureAsync();

   // Set the stream position to the beginning.
   captureStream1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

   MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
   Picture picture1 = library.SavePictureToCameraRoll("image1", captureStream1);
}
```

Comment: Brother, can u tell me wat it represent "captureStream1"